# Should you mention "dollars" after a price?

Tags: word-choice

"The company has revenues of $40 billion" Should I add dollars so it becomes: "The company has revenues of $40 billion dollars" or is the $ sign before the number sufficient?

Comment: The $ at the front is sufficient; putting both "$" and the word "dollars" is redundant and (to me, at least) looks unprofessional.

Comment: As @Hellion says writing '$50 dollars' involves repetition of the word 'dollar'.  The only time when the dollar sign does not do the job properly is when it is unclear which currency is being discussed. In the case of a discussion involving, say, the [Zimbabwean dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbabwean_dollar) writing $1 million is confusing unless you have already made it clear that you have already referred to 'Zimbabwean dollars', ZWD or ZWL. However '$1,000,00 ZWD' still involves repetition and the dollar sign should be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

If a currency symbol is used in writing, it takes the place of the word which is the name of the currency, thus $1 or one dollar, $50 or 50 dollars. A money amount written with the sign before the figures is read aloud with the word after the number: "$50" is read aloud as "fifty dollars". Use either the symbol or the word, never both.